# different primitive data type entry in the same class algorithm

Tags: java, polymorphism

```
public class Quicksort{
private int[] numbers;
private int number;
public void sort(int[] values) {// check for empty or null array
    if (values ==null || values.length==0){
        return;
     }
     this.numbers = values;
     number = values.length;
     quicksort(0, number - 1);
}
```

I want to use such a quicksort algorithm in Java, BUT WITH different input, NOT just integer array as depicted in line No 2 `private int[] numbers`.

So the general question here, is how to "send" to the algorithm different input?
An obvious answer would be to create multiple polymorphism methods each for different input data like these:

```
public void(int [] inArray{
   do something
}
public void (char[] inArray){
   do something else.....
} etc etc
```

or using polymorphism to declare the  `public void sort(int[] values)` multiple times with different input, such as `public void sort(char[] values)`, `public void sort(double[] values)`
but all the above, is not good programming and too much code (declaration of multiple variables etc :-(
So I need something (probably template?) to "instruct" the class to "accept" many different kind of input and obviously output the same kind of data...

Comment: You may want to look into the comparable interface; http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: Unfortunately, such is life: if it weren't an array of primitives, you could use generics, but with the way the generics are "implemented" in Java, repeating the code is your only choice.

Comment: I ended up repeating the code. Not elegant, but "that's life" ...:-)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `Comparable` interface

See here for more information:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html